# Using the Editor plugin without an ajax call?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, code-behind

I am populating my html Table in WEbForms.aspx.cs file using simple SQL query and For Loop for Thead and TBody

So far I have applied Table1.dataTable() and it works perfectly fine.

I want to edit this rows using Editor.
Most of the examples are asking for Ajax call.

Here is my code
for populating through ASpx.cs

```
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            if (bAdd == true)
            {
                html.Append("<span class='btn btn-info btn-sm' style='margin:5px'><a href='#my_modal' data-toggle='modal' style='color:white; text-decoration:none'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i>Add New Vendor</a></span>");
            }



            //Table start.
            html.Append("<table id='XGrid' class='table table-bordered table-hover' border='0' cellspacing='0' > ");

            //  <table border="0" id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0"  cellpadding="0" align="center" width="100%" >

            #region table Header
            html.Append("<thead>");

            if(bEdit==true)   html.Append("<th>Edit</th>");

            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {

                html.Append("<th>");

                html.Append(column.ColumnName);

                html.Append("</th>");

            }

            html.Append("</tr>");
            html.Append("</thead>");
            #endregion


            #region table Rows

            //Building the Data rows.
            html.Append("<tbody>");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {

                html.Append("<tr>");

                if (bEdit == true)
                {
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    //<span class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></span>
                    html.Append("<span class='btn btn-success btn-sm btn-circle'><a href='#my_modal' data-toggle='modal' style='color:white; text-decoration:none'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a></span>");
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {

                    html.Append("<td>");

                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);

                    html.Append("</td>");

                }

                html.Append("</tr>");

            }

            html.Append("</tbody>");

            #endregion

            //Table end.
            html.Append("</table>");

            //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
            plAdd.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Is there a way I can use Editor plugin without Ajax call?